# Difference in sample means showing its estimated standard error

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I've been using the [Welch t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test) for finding p-values for whether two means are the same, from populations with unequal variances (but samples look normally distributed).

However, sometimes I have a case like 79.4±0.5 vs 73.5±0.4 where the p-value would just be astronomically small. A more useful way of characterizing this would be a difference in means accompanied with a standard deviation (how confident I am of that difference in means).

What are the best statistical ways to go about this?

TLDR:

- Unequal variances
- Normally distributed
- Diff. in means is there; I want to characterise how **big** it is based on sample data

Answer (score 1):

As an example for the first population, I will take $77.4\pm 0.5$ to mean
a sample from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=77.4,\sigma=0.5),$ and similarly for the second population. [If you intended to write confidence intervals, then
my standard deviations will not be what you intended, but the *methods*
shown in my example below still apply.]

Accordingly, suppose you have $n = 20$ observations from each population and
perform a Welch two-sample t test for differences in population means.
In R, it looks like this:

```
set.seed(2020)
x1 = rnorm(20, 77.4, 0.5)  
x2 = rnorm(20, 73.5, 0.4)
mean(x1);  sd(x1)
[1] 77.34882
[1] 0.7131236
mean(x2);  sd(x2)
[1] 73.68158
[1] 0.3486032

t.test(x1, x2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = 20.661, df = 27.59, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 3.303421 4.031060
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 77.34882  73.68158
```

Notice that the output gives a 95% confidence interval
$(3.303, 4.031)$ for the difference $\mu_1 - \mu_2$ in population
means.

The difference $\bar X_1 - \bar X_2$ between the two sample means
estimates the difference $\mu_1 - \mu_2$ between the two population means.
For independent samples, the variance of the difference in sample means is

$$Var(\bar X_1 - \bar X_2) = Var(\bar X_1) + Var(\bar X_2)
=\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1} + \frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2},$$
estimated by
$$\widehat{Var}(\bar X_1 - \bar X_2) = \frac{S_1^2}{n_1} + \frac{S_2^2}{n_2},$$
where $S_1^2$ and $S_2^2$ are the respective sample variances.

The 95% confidence interval in the R output for the Welch two-sample t test
is of the form
$$\bar X_1 - \bar X_2 \pm t^*\sqrt{\frac{S_1^2}{n_1} + \frac{S_2^2}{n_2}},$$

where $t^*$ cuts probability $0.025 = 2.5\%$ from the upper tail of
Student's t distribution with $\nu^\prime = 27.59$ degrees of freedom.
To get $\nu^\prime$ you need to use the formula for the degrees of
freedom of a Welch test. (It involves sample sizes and sample variances
and satisfies the inequality $\min(n_1-1,n_2-1) \le \nu^\prime \le n_1 + n_1 - 2.$ The computer output above uses $t^* = 2.050.)$

```
qt(.975, 27.59)
[1] 2.049779
```

If you just want to show the estimated difference in population means
along with its standard deviation, you might write
$$\bar X_1 - \bar X_2 \pm \sqrt{\frac{S_1^2}{n_1} + \frac{S_2^2}{n_2}},$$
being careful to mention that you are showing a 'standard error' on the right and
*not* a 'margin of error' as in a confidence interval.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the p-value for the hypothesis test is to report a *confidence interval* for the mean difference.  In cases where there is an obvious difference this ought to show up in the confidence interval.  If you are using the `t.test` function in `R` then the confidence interval is reported along with the test results.